# how to find Queries that are in lock or latch state in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

i want a sql query to find all the query that are being executed currently and in lock state or latch state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SHOW_OPEN_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html)

```
show open tables where In_Use > 0;
```